# Is a DB index possible to optimize a pg_search, pg_search_scope method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pg-search

I'm working to add search to my PostgreSQL 9.1 rails app. Here is the setup:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_content, :against => :content
```

Rails C, command:

```
 Comment.where(:commentable_id => 33).search_by_content('pgsql').count
```

Rails Log:

```
(348.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 33 AND (((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comments"."content"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'pgsql' || ' '''))))
```

After install the gem, and setting up the comment model, the instructions mentioned nothing about adding a db index to optimize performance. Given the query is already taking 348.1ms locally, I'm curious can this be optimized to be more performant?

Thanks

Comment: For those of us who don't speak Rails, what underlying queries does this `pg_search` run? Is it full-text search? If so, read the PostgreSQL manual on full-text search, which discusses GiST indexes for fulltext.

Comment: The query which is run is displayed above in the "Rails Log" which shows the raw SQL being sent to PostgreSQL

Comment: Gah, I'm blind. Sorry. So yes, it's using full-text search.

Answer (score 2):

Rails appears to be using full-text search - see the [PostgreSQL documentation on full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html), particularly the [creating indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX) section.

Rails is doing some very odd things with the tsearch2 expression that may make it harder to create an index that PostgreSQL will recognise as matching. See [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10880327/398670).

Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to verify that it's using the index.