# Indexing large documents with pg_search and GIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, pg-search

I'm using Rails 3 to build a forum for myself and my friends (I didn't use one out of the box for a variety of reasons) and I'm at the point where I'm trying to implement full text search for the forum. Nothing fancy - just if someone searches the string "morning", I want to be able to show a list of all forum threads with posts containing the word "morning". I've been using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) for searching, but it's slow (5+ seconds) since we're already at 300 forum threads with 200k+ posts, some of which are 4k+ characters just in a single post. So I have this migration for multisearch:

```
class CreatePgSearchDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    say_with_time("Creating table for pg_search multisearch") do
      create_table :pg_search_documents do |t|
        t.text :content
        t.belongs_to :searchable, :polymorphic => true, :index => true
        t.timestamps null: false
      end
      add_index :pg_search_documents, :content, using: "gin"
      PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Post)
      PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Reply)
    end
  end
end
```

But it's failing when I run the migration with this error:

```
PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row size 3080 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "index_pg_search_documents_on_content"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

So far Googling has gotten me the following:

- GIN indexes are better than GIST indexes for handling 100,000+ lexemes. This implies to me that GIN indexes should be capable of handling posts that are only 700 words
- I had a guess that this error was about a *single value* rather than the length of the *document*, and was worried this was caused by the fact that I allow a subset of HTML tags in forum posts, so instead of storing post.content I now store post.sanitized_content. This strips all HTML, then replaces punctuation with spaces, then strips duplicates, like so: `ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(content).gsub(/[^\w ]/, ' ').squeeze(" ")`. This got the error message down to `index row size 2848 exceeds maximum 2712`, so it clearly did *something*, but not enough.
- I then sanity checked that pg_search actually allows me to use dynamic methods like that, and it's not just secretly failing silently. According to the docs, "However, if you call any dynamic methods in :against, the following strategy will be used", so they seem to be handled just fine.

Relevant pieces of my implementation of Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  multisearchable against: [:subject, :sanitized_content]

  def sanitized_content
    ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(content).gsub(/[^\w ]/, ' ').squeeze(" ")
  end
end
```

(I have also tried remove :subject from the multisearchable-against array, in case it was an unsanitized subject causing the issues; this got me down to `row size 2800` in the error, but didn't fix it.)

So... what am I missing? Shouldn't GIN indexes be able to handle large text documents? Do I need to turn my documents into tsvectors first like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880327/proper-full-text-index-rails-postgresql-pg-search)? It keeps suggesting "full text indexing" but I thought that's what this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of future people Googling: tentatively, using

```
execute "CREATE INDEX idx_fts_search_content ON pg_search_documents USING gin(to_tsvector('english', content))
```

instead of

```
add_index :pg_search_documents, :content, using: "gin"
```

has fixed it. Index so far isn't doing much, it takes a good 8.1s to search everything, but at least the migration runs now!

EDIT: Missed an important thing. The actual command should be:

```
execute "CREATE INDEX idx_fts_post_content ON posts USING gin(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(\"posts\".\"content\"::text, '')))"
```

If you don't have the coalesce(), it won't use the index.